# R ODBC - Querying Column name with spaces

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I am trying to query through R OBDC. But one Column name has space on it. For example, `[Account No]`.

I am using this code to query:

```
esiid_ac <- sqlQuery(myconn, paste("
 SELECT * FROM CustomerUsage WHERE ((CustomerUsage.Account No ='", 12345, "')) ", sep=""),as.is=TRUE)
```

I am getting the following error:

> [1] "42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near 'No'."                           [2]
>   "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect '\n SELECT * FROM
>   CustomerUsage WHERE ((CustomerUsage.Account No ='678987')) '

How to solve this?

Can I read this table with column index instead of column names?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

After tinkering around with quotes a little bit, this worked for me:

```
df <- sqlQuery(myconn, 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE "column name" =123', as.is=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried square brackets (They work for me when there are special characters in column names)?

```
esiid_ac <- sqlQuery(myconn, paste(" SELECT * FROM CustomerUsage WHERE ((CustomerUsage.[Account No] ='", 12345, "')) ", sep=""),as.is=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\"COL_NAME\"` instead of `COL_NAME` and use that as you would always use it. For example:

```
esiid_ac <- sqlQuery(myconn, "SELECT * FROM CustomerUsage WHERE \"Account No\" = 12345")
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to put the column name like [Account No] and then try?

Answer (score 1):

You can try...

```
df <- sqlQuery(myconn, "SELECT * FROM mytab WHERE `crazy column name` =123", as.is=TRUE)
```

Comment: Tried this too. The way R handles spaces in column. It gives out the same error.